# How to pass data from pre middleware to route handler?

Tags: hapi.js

I have pre response something like this

```
function middleware(req: HapiRequest, res: Hapi.ReplyNoContinue) {
    res({data: "something"})
}
```

And later I need to access the object from route handler how can I do that?

Comment: Singleton? Global object?

Comment: Could you elaborate question please?

Comment: As far as i understood you are looking for a global object, right?

Comment: After pre hapi middleware I am looking to access data which I get there, I need access to that data from route handler.  So basically I need to pass data from pre middleware to route handler.

Answer (score 1):

When defining a route with a prerequisite, you may assign a name for each prerequisite. Like this:

```
server.route({
        method: `get`,
        path: `/pre`,
        config: {
            pre: [
                {
                    method: function (request, reply) {
                        reply(`pizza`);
                    },
                    assign: `cheekibreeki`
                }
            ]
        },
        handler: function (request, reply) {
            reply(request.pre.cheekibreeki);
        }
});
```

I made a route and assigned name `cheekibreeki` to it's prerequisite which replies `pizza`. Then the replied data inside a prerequisite is available in route handler inside a `request.pre['assignedname']`.

Another way is using `request.app` object.

If you don't want to proceed to the route handler, you must use `reply().takeover()` method.

Hope this helps.